# mysql: get row value where ID match in case function

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to get value from `t5` table as below where `t4.slot` match `t5.Id` using case but always I get value from first row, when `t4.slot Id='2'`, the it would get value from `t5` second row values.

**table: t1** data come from this table
[image]

**expected output:**
[image]

**table: t5** And I'm trying to use this table fields as criteria in the case with between function according to ID.

[image]

```
select t1.TraineeID, 
       t3.BatchID,
       t4.Slot,
       t2.attnDate,
       min(t1.attnTime) as in_time, 
       max(t1.attnTime) as out_time,
       (CASE WHEN t5.ID='1' and t1.attnTime<t5.inTime THEN 'P' 
             WHEN t5.ID='2' and t1.attnTime<t5.inTime THEN 'P'
        ELSE 'Late-In' END) AS Status
from tbl_attn_temp t1, tbl_assigned t3
join (select distinct attnDate from tbl_attn_temp)t2
left outer join tbl_batch t4 on t3.BatchID=t4.BatchID
left outer join tbl_threshold t5 on t4.Slot=t5.ID
where t1.attndate = t2.attnDate and t1.TraineeID=t3.TraineeID 
and t4.Slot=(CASE 
     WHEN t5.ID='1' THEN t1.attnTime BETWEEN t5.minLimit AND t5.maxLitmit
     WHEN t5.ID='2' THEN t1.attnTime BETWEEN t5.minLimit AND t5.maxLitmit
     END)
group by t1.TraineeID, t2.attnDate
```

Any help would appreciate.

Comment: Please give sample input,expected output and explain what you want to achieve a little more specifically.

Comment: Is "expected output:" actually "t4"? And, just curious,  why is trainee_id a string?

Comment: Also, generally date and time are stored as a single entity

Comment: no, expected output come from t1 and t3, t4, t5 join with this, trainee id here not issue actually, I just need that t5.ID is in case that will return minTime, maxTime where match with t4.Slot